# Is knowing whether the number is signed or unsigned just a compiler concern?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, cpu-architecture, twos-complement

I was recently studying about **two's complement** and how we can use the **same** hardware to do add, subtract and multiply two numbers regardless of whether they are signed or unsigned.
Then i remembered that in **static compiled languages** such as **C** we need to explicitly tell to the ***compiler*** if the number is signed or unsigned.

I Do understand that while the CPU ***ALU*** (i think) does not need (or does not want) to know if the number is signed or unsigned, but the **compiler needs!** so we can do the correct computations, comparisons, and handle input/output better.

My low-level inclined question is:

> At the **lowest level**, does the computer REALLY doesn't need to know if the numbers are signed or not, is it really a **COMPILER-ONLY concern** ?

*I Did some experiments here some of the interesting results*:

[(C Code) Changing if the b is signed or unsigned in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZzAb.png)

[Generated Assembly from the C code (comparison parts only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jtkj.png)

Not much of a difference in the assembly code, but it does differ, which i found interesting.
So it seems that **signed or unsigned** is just a compiler and programmer concern, so we can generate the correct code, i am missing something ?, some low-level detail ?, does the cpu totally ignores if the number is signed or not ?

> The cpu **totally ignores** if the number is signed or unsigned ?

Comment: The CPU doesn't always ignore if the number is signed or not. That's why we have `MUL` and `IMUL`, `SAR` and `SHR`.

Comment: So MOST of the time we can safely ignore if the number is signed, that's the power of two's complement

Comment: No we can't: which is smaller? `0x0000` or `0xFFFF`? The processor does not have a signed and unsigned version: the programmer must test the appropriate flags. By specifying `signed` or `unsigned` the C compiler does that for you.

Comment: ...and used as an array index or pointer arithmetic, it really does matter for the larger index values (more than half the unsigned range).

Comment: @BottomExplorer Basically, we can only ignore that for addition and subtraction.  But these are already the two most common operations, so it's quite useful.

Comment: Most of the time? Besides addition and subtraction (`ADD`, `SUB`, `ADC`, `SBB`, `DEC`, `INC`, `CMP`), only left shift (`SHL`/`SAL`) works on both signed and unsigned numbers. Multiply, division, right shift,  negation (`NEG`), `CWD/CDQ/CQO`, and `MOVZX/MOVSX` don't. And if you consider SIMD instructions, many addition and subtraction instructions are signedness-aware.

Comment: Even though ADD & SUB work on both signed and unsigned numbers, they set the flags so that we can tell overflow: overflow is different depending on whether the addition was intended as signed or unsigned -- we would test different flags.

Comment: @W.Chang Multiplication works, too, if you do not need the high word of the result.

Comment: @fuz Yes, you're right. That's the case for `IMUL` with two or three operands. For `MUL/IMUL` with 1 operand, `DX/EDX/RDX` is modified and will be different.